# Access definitions from sublocale

Tags: locale, isabelle

In isabelle, I have the following sketch of a hierarchy of locales:

```
locale Base =
  fixes foo :: "nat set"
begin
  definition small :: "nat ⇒ nat set" where
    "small n = {m ∈ foo. n * m < 100}"
end
locale Other =
  fixes n :: nat
sublocale Other ⊆ Base "{..<n}" .
```

I now want to access the definition of `small` as interpreted in `Other`:

```
term Base.small (* works but parameters have to be provided *)
context Other begin term small end (* works, but needs context *)
term Other.small (* does not work *)
```

I would like the last line to work, or something equivalent so that I can refer to the correct definition of `Other.small` from global context. I reality, `Other` includes parameters, too, and I have a theorem that relates different interpretations of `Other`. For example I want to write something like this:

```
lemma card_small_lt: "n < m ==> card (Other.small n) < card (Other.small m)"
  sorry
```

---

I have figured out a work around, but it leads to a bit of manual typing in the  long run. First, I name the sublocale, then I introduce abbreviations in a context:

```
sublocale Other ⊆ B: Base "{..<n}" .
context Other
begin
abbreviation "small ≡ B.small"
end
term Other.small (* does now work! *)
```

The question remains, if the above can be automated, I'd rather not write an abbreviation for each definition I want to use from the outside.