# Access a definition from a locale

Tags: isabelle

Specific example: Let's say I have demonstrated that I have a `graph` in the sense of https://www.isa-afp.org/theories/category3/#FreeCategory.html :

```
lemma i_have_a_graph: shows "graph Obj Arr Dom Cod"
  sorry
```

where the symbols `Obj`, `Arr`, `Dom`, and `Cod` were defined earlier in the file. This gives me access to the lemmas and theorems stated within the `graph` locale.

How do I use the symbol `path` defined within the `graph` locale?

---

Related question with no answers: [Access definitions from sublocale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57331563/2318074)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do it using a lemma but by the `interpretation` command:

`interpretation MyGraph: graph Obj Are Dom Cod   <proof>`

Of course, the `<proof>` could use your lemma, but you don't need to prove such a lemma separately.

Now `MyGraph.path` refers to the `path` component of this instance.

See https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/dist/Isabelle/doc/locales.pdf